# How to display data from server in pie chart?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I want to display data in pie chart. Data is retrieved from server in `JSON` format i.e. single `int` value and I want to display it using pie chart. Suppose that data is `66`, then i want to show that `66%` full in pie chart.

I have retrieved data but **not able to find the function in javascript to accept data**

For Ex. :

```
$(function(){
  $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "Full", value:  66,   color: "#FC4349" },
    { title: "Empty",      value:  34,   color: "#6DBCDB" },
  ]);
});`
```

Then instead of already defined values in above function i want to accept value from server and display in pie chart.

in index.html I added statement
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/79448/feed/last.json?callback=?', function(data){
                           $("div").append(data.field1 + " ");
                   });
        **var x=data.field1;**
    });
});
</script>`

---

This is my index.js file :

`$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart( dataFromServer);`

```
`$(function(){
  `$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
        {  title:"Full" value: dataFromServer.y1, color: "#FC4349"  },
        {  title: "Empty" value: dataFromServer.y2, color: "#6DBCDB" },
      ]);
});`
`var formattedData = [];`
```

// "dataFromServer" contains an array of differently-formatted objects

`for ( var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++ ){
        formattedData.push({ 
                             value: dataFromServer[i].y,
                           });
    }
$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart( formattedData );`

So please tell me is this way i should write in index.js file???
                                                                         **dataFromServer.y1=x;**                                                                                                    Please suggest me the correct way.

Comment: How you are retrieving data in json format? Can you please share Fiddle here...

Comment: This is the code :  on clicking Get JSON data i get value from server i.e.66..which i have push   <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/79448/feed/last.json?callback=?', function(data){
           
                $("div").append(data.field1 + " ");
            
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends upon the form of your data. A;; you're going to do is use variables instead of literals. For instance, if your data is an array of objects with a title, value, and color, you could just call:

```
// "dataFromServer" is an array of appropriately formatted objects
$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart( dataFromServer);
```

If, on the other hand, you have a complex object you need to map out, you could do it explicitly like so:

```
// "dataFromServer" contains all of the right data, but in different locations
$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: dataFromServer.x1, value: dataFromServer.y1, color: dataFromServer.z1 },
    { title: dataFromServer.x2, value: dataFromServer.y2, color: dataFromServer.z2 },
]);
```

Most likely you will have an array of differently formatted object, which you will want to turn into an array of objects formatted in this manner, in which case you would want to loop through the objects from the server and create a new variable from them:

```
// formattedData is the array that will be passed into the chart
var formattedData = [];

// "dataFromServer" contains an array of differently-formatted objects
for ( var i = 0; i < dataFromServer.length; i++ ){
    formattedData.push({ title: dataFromServer[i].x,
                         value: dataFromServer[i].y,
                         color: dataFromServer[i].z });
}

$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart( formattedData );
```

**Addendum:**

Upon comment clarification, I am adding the following. Assuming the Title and Color values are static (i.e. not coming from the database), you may simply insert the integer "values" into the code directly, like so:

```
// "mySanFranciscoDataValue" is the single integer you're trying to insert
//    into the chart. Simply reference it directly, whether it's a
//    variable or a function. Presumably you will have two of them,
//    one for each city, so I've included a "myNewYorkDataValue" too.
$("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "San Francisco", value:  mySanFranciscoDataValue,   color: "#FC4349" },
    { title: "New York",      value:  myNewYorkDataValue,   color: "#6DBCDB" },
]);
```

Comment: Well, in your answer you said you have retrieved data. What is this data? Is it an array? If so, that already is the dataFromServer array, just reference it by its existing name.

Comment: It is the integer value.i am not able to understand how to reference it.i am new to JS..so can't get it. thanks for answering :)

Comment: I have added an addendum to my initial answer. In short, however you have that value (say it's in `var x`), then you need only reference that value in place of the integer literals in your array (for instance `value: x` instead of `value: 66`).

Comment: I have added code of both index.html and index.js...please go through it and tell me bcoz i am unable to get output.i try out diffrent ways..bt it didnt wrk.

Comment: I think it's important for you to learn a little bit more about javascript objects and the service you're hitting. If I knew what "data" was being returned I could give you working code, but -- and I mean no offense -- I don't think you understand enough about javascript to effectively understand the answers you're being given. Regarding my javascript that you put in your index.js, all four code snippets were alternatives. You shouldn't be using all of them at once. If you have specific questions of how to accomplish something in Javascript it would be most appropriate to open more questions.